# Joomla, create custom php page that list some results

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-sef-urls, joomla3.4

I try to create a custom results page for my custom entities (database).
So, i have in home page a search box, the form have to redirect to this "custom" page.

What is the preferable way to accomplish this?

I tried to add new php page to my template, but how can i achieve SEF url in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Not specially the best way, but a simple one :
For displaying results, you could create a Menu-item containing an Article.
The search box form would be submitted to this Menu-item.
In order to process these data here, you could use an plugin like [Sourcerer](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) allowing to write PHP in Articles, Modules, etc.
This solution using Menu-items, it would be SEF compliant,

Comment: ok this sound good thanks. Now i have created a new module (myModule), a new article (my-results-page) and set the myModule visible only for my-results-page. So i can process (and print) data in myModule code. Seems legit?

Comment: Yes that's another way to do it.